# Why doesn't php sleep work in the windows-subsystem-linux?

Tags: php, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

The system is Ubuntu 20.04 of windows wsl. I install php by apt install php.The version of php is 7.4.

I type `php -r "sleep(2);"` in the linux shell. But it does not work,end immediately

Comment: Interestingly, `usleep()` does work.

Comment: I write the answer but the answer was been deleted by moderator.

Answer (score 3):

There's a bug into WSL v1 and Ubuntu 20.04.
Until the fix doesn't comes out, my work around was creating my own sleep function, as follow:

```
function waitForSec($sec) {
    $arr = [];
    $siginf = [];
    pcntl_sigtimedwait($arr,$siginf,$sec);
}
```

Cheers!!!!